# When I try to install to thread module in python3 that error occurs:

Tags: python-3.x

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement thread
ERROR: No matching distribution found for thread

Comment: `thread` is in the stdlib, you don't need to install it through pip.

Answer (score 0):

The thread module has been changed to `_thread`. You don't need to pip install this module.

Answer (score 0):

The thread module has been renamed to _thread in Python 3. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3; however, you should consider using the high-level threading module instead.
for python install threading module:

```
pip3 install thread6
```

for more information go to [thread6 · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/thread6/)